# Catch-all should pass path to index.php in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

In `apache` I have an `.htaccess` that will rewrite from `http://server/api/any/path/i/want` to `http://server/api/index.php` if no file or folder is found.

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I'm moving to `docker` and will use `nginx` instead and I want to re-write the `rewrite`.

Important to note is that using `apache`and `.htaccess` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/api/any/path/i/want` and not the re-written url (`index.php....`).

I'm not that well versed with `nginx` but from posts on SO I've figured some things out.

Relevant section of `site.conf`

```
location / {
    root /app/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @missing;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}

location @missing {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/api/index.php permanent;
}
```

The above config will unfortunately only redirect to `index.php` and is as far I've managed to get.

How can I do the same thing in `nginx`?

Comment: If you want unknown URIs to be handled by `/index.php`, use `try_files $uri /index.php?$args =404;` instead of `try_files $uri @missing;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical nginx configuration for PHP-FPM.

```
server {

 root /app/html;

 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   }

}
```

Notice the differences from your example:

1. Removed the unnecessary `@missing` location block.
2. Removed the `try_files` statement from the `.php` location block.
3. Moved the `root` declaration to the server block. If you need to have different roots, please specify this in your question.
4. The only `try_files` statement includes the full path for your `api/index.php`.

If a request comes for a non-existing path, it will be handled by your `/app/html/api/index.php` script, acting as a global entry-point.

Comment: close but actually not 100% when I tested it. It's not working for `/api/`. It gives a 304.

Comment: Nevermind... figured it out. I needed to add another for the path `/` since that's where the static stuff is and one for `api`.

Comment: Great. Sorry, didn't see your messages yesterday.